# Server/Client program not working when I try to implement multithreading

Tags: java, multithreading, server, client

I am creating a Server Client program which works before I try to implement multithreading on the server. I am unsure what is causing the issue. The client connects to the server, after selecting the upload or download option and sends the first line of the file, then the client crashes with this exception:

```
java.io.EOFException
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream$PeekInputStream.readFully(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.readShort(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readStreamHeader(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at Client.upload(Client.java:66)
    at Client.main(Client.java:99)
```

Client Code

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class Client {
    public static void download(String filename)
    {
        try {
            InetAddress host = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
            Socket socket = null;
            ObjectOutputStream oos = null;
            ObjectInputStream ois = null;

            socket = new Socket(host.getHostName(), 8001);
            Writer out = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new 
            FileOutputStream(filename),"utf8"));

            oos = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
            oos.writeObject("Download");
            oos.writeObject(filename);
            oos.close();
            socket.close();

            while(true)
            {
                socket = new Socket(host.getHostName(), 8001);
                oos = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
                System.out.println("Line request sent");
                oos.writeObject("Request");
                ois = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
                String message = (String) ois.readObject();
                if(message.equalsIgnoreCase("%end%"))break;
                out.write(message + "\n");
                ois.close();
                socket.close();
            }
            out.close();
            oos.close();
        }
        catch(IOException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void upload(String filename)
    {
        try {
            InetAddress host = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
            Socket socket = null;
            ObjectOutputStream oos = null;
            ObjectInputStream ois = null;
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename));
            socket = new Socket(host.getHostName(), 8001);
            oos = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
            oos.writeObject("Upload");
            oos.writeObject(filename);
            oos.close();
            socket.close();
            String line = null;
            while((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
                socket = new Socket(host.getHostName(), 8001);
                oos = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
                System.out.println("Sending line to Socket Server");
                oos.writeObject(line);
                ois = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
                String message = (String) ois.readObject();
                System.out.println("Message: " + message);
                ois.close();
                oos.close();
                Thread.sleep(100);
            }
            socket = new Socket(host.getHostName(), 8001);
            oos = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
            System.out.println("Sending end of file to Server");
            oos.writeObject("%end%");
            oos.close();
            socket.close();

            in.close();
        }
        catch(IOException | ClassNotFoundException | InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int i = 0;
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        do
        {
            System.out.println("Enter '-u' to upload or '-d' to download");
            String input = scanner.next();
            System.out.println("Enter the filename");
            String filename = scanner.next();
            if(input.equalsIgnoreCase("-u")) {
                System.out.println("Uploading " + filename);
                upload(filename);
                i = 0;
            }
            else if(input.equalsIgnoreCase("-d")) {
                System.out.println("Downloading " + filename);
                download(filename);
                i = 0;
            }
            else{
                System.out.println("Invalid input try again");
                i = 1;
            }
        }while(i == 1);
        scanner.close();
    }
}
```

Server Code before multithreading

```
import java.io.*;
import java.lang.ClassNotFoundException;
import java.net.*;

public class Server 
{
    private static ServerSocket server;
    private static int port = 8001;

    public static void upload(String fileName)
    {
        try {
            System.out.println("File Uploading");
            Writer out = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(fileName), 
            "utf-8"));
            System.out.println("Created " + fileName);
            while(true)
            {
                System.out.println("Waiting for next line");
                Socket socket = server.accept();
                ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
                String message = (String) ois.readObject();
                if(message.equalsIgnoreCase("%end%"))break;
                out.write(message + "\n");
                System.out.println("Message Received: " + message);
                ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
                oos.writeObject("Server Received: " + message);
                ois.close();
                oos.close();
                socket.close();
            }
            out.close();
            System.out.println("Shutting down Socket server!!");
            server.close();
        }
        catch(IOException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void download(String fileName)
    {
        try {
            Socket socket = null;
            System.out.println("Selected Download");
            System.out.println(fileName + " Downloading");

            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));
            ObjectOutputStream oos = null;
            String line = null;
            while((line = in.readLine()) != null)
            {
                try
                {
                    socket = server.accept();
                    oos = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
                    oos.writeObject(line);
                    System.out.println("Line " + line + " sent to client");
                    oos.close();
                    Thread.sleep(100);
                } 
                catch(InterruptedException e) 
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            System.out.println("Sending end of file");
            Socket endSocket = server.accept();
            ObjectOutputStream end = new ObjectOutputStream(endSocket.getOutputStream());
            end.writeObject("%end%");
            end.close();
            in.close();
            System.out.println("Shutting down Socket server!!");
            server.close();
        }
        catch(IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException
    {
        while(true)
        {
            try {
                server = new ServerSocket(port);
                System.out.println("Waiting for upload or download request from client");
                Socket socketUpDown = server.accept();

                ObjectInputStream request = new ObjectInputStream(socketUpDown.getInputStream());
                String upDown = (String)request.readObject();
                if(upDown.equals("Upload"))
                {
                    upload((String)request.readObject());
                }

                else if(upDown.equals("Download"))
                {
                    download((String)request.readObject());
                }
                socketUpDown.close();
            }
            catch(IOException | ClassNotFoundException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Server Code After Multithreading

```
import java.io.*;
import java.lang.ClassNotFoundException;
import java.net.*;

public class Server 
{
    private static ServerSocket server;
    private static int port = 8001;

    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException
    {
        try
        {
            server = new ServerSocket(port);
            int counter = 0;
            System.out.println("Server Started ....");
            while(true)
            {
                counter++;
                Socket serverClient = server.accept();
                System.out.println("A new client is connected : " + serverClient);
                ServerClientThread sct = new ServerClientThread(serverClient, counter);
                sct.start();
            }
        }catch(Exception e){
              e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    private static class ServerClientThread extends Thread 
    {
        private int clientNo;
        public ServerClientThread(Socket socket, int clientNo)
        {
            this.clientNo = clientNo;
        }

        public void run()
        {
            try {
                System.out.println("Waiting for upload or download request from client");
                Socket socketUpDown = server.accept();

                ObjectInputStream request = new ObjectInputStream(socketUpDown.getInputStream());
                String upDown = (String)request.readObject();
                if(upDown.equals("Upload"))
                {
                    upload((String)request.readObject());
                }

                else if(upDown.equals("Download"))
                {
                    download((String)request.readObject());
                }
                socketUpDown.close();
            }
            catch(IOException | ClassNotFoundException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            finally{
                System.out.println("Client -" + clientNo + " exit!! ");
            }
        }

        public static void upload(String fileName)
        {
            try {
                System.out.println("File Uploading");
                Writer out = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new 
                FileOutputStream(fileName), "utf-8"));
                System.out.println("Created " + fileName);
                while(true)
                {
                    System.out.println("Waiting for next line");
                    Socket socket = server.accept();
                    ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
                    String message = (String) ois.readObject();
                    if(message.equalsIgnoreCase("%end%"))break;
                    out.write(message + "\n");
                    System.out.println("Message Received: " + message);
                    ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
                    oos.writeObject("Received" + message);
                    ois.close();
                    oos.close();
                    socket.close();
                }
                out.close();
                System.out.println("Shutting down Socket server!!");
                server.close();
            }
            catch(IOException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        public static void download(String fileName)
        {
            try {
                Socket socket = null;
                System.out.println("Selected Download");
                System.out.println(fileName + " Downloading");

                BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));
                ObjectOutputStream oos = null;
                String line = null;
                while((line = in.readLine()) != null)
                {
                    try{
                        socket = server.accept();
                        oos = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
                        oos.writeObject(line);
                        System.out.println("Line " + line + " written to file");
                        oos.close();
                        Thread.sleep(100);
                        } 
                    catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                   }
                System.out.println("Sending end of file");
                Socket endSocket = server.accept();
                ObjectOutputStream end = new ObjectOutputStream(endSocket.getOutputStream());
                end.writeObject("%end%");
                end.close();
                in.close();
                System.out.println("Shutting down Socket server!!");
                server.close();
            }
            catch(IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You are calling `accept()` twice and throwing away the first result.

Comment: Thank you I found the issue with using accept multiple times. I rebuilt the code to make it more efficient. i didn't understand exactly what the accept method actually did.

Comment: It accepts a client connection in the form of a socket. You are passing the first-accepted socket to the `ServerClientThread` constructor and then throwing it away instead of storing it into a class member. The `run()` method should not call `accept()` again, it should use that class member.